# Access CommandItems programmatically with ArcObjects in ArcGIS Engine application

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, c#, arcgis-engine

I'd like to programmatically execute a command in my ArcGIS Engine application with ArcObjects. I know in Desktop I would do it like this:

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICommandBars commandBars = m_application.Document.CommandBars;
ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UID uid = new ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UIDClass();
uid.Value = cmdname; // Example: "esriFramework.HelpContentsCommand" or "{D74B2F25-AC90-11D2-87F8-0000F8751720}"
ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICommandItem commandItem = commandBars.Find(uid, false, false);
commandItem.Execute();
```

but IApplication is not available in an Engine environment. Is there an alternative way for standalone (ArcGIS Engine) applications to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESRI have "improved" their forum site and it's now hard to find any of the archived threads but I did find this code fragment in a thread from 2008. I've done very little in Engine so this may be a red herring?

```
ICommand command = new ControlsZoomToSelectedCommandClass();
command.OnCreate(this.axMapControl1.Object);
command.OnClick();
```